# How to do custom async callbacks like Android Fragments do?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, callback

after having so much fun with Android fragments talking to each other and to the activity. I'm excited to try making some async callbacks from a background service. For my purpose, I just want a listener in the activity getting a callback from a background service.

In the background service called SomeService, I've created an interface and instantiate a member listener:

```
private OnSomethingHappenedListener mListener;
public interface OnSomethingHappenedListener {
    void onSomethingHappened(String mWhateverHappened);
}
```

And in where something should happen, I have the following code

```
if (mListener != null)
    {
        mListener.onSomethingHappened(AHHHappened);
    }else
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"mListener for the interface method is null for some reason?");
    }
```

Then in the activity for receiving the callback, I have implemented the contract, and overrided the method.

```
public class listenerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SomeService.OnSomethingHappenedListener{

    // Receive Callback
        @Override
        public void onSomethingHappened(String mWhateverHappened) { Log.i(TAG,mWhateverHappened);
        }
}
```

I've done stuff very similar to this with the fragments and no error, but for some reason in this case the mListener is null when the service runs, and couldn't start the call. What initialization step(s) am I missing? Thanks.

**EDIT 4/6/2017**
Changed from creating a listener and then attaching it TO implementing it in the class and then overriding the method.

What I really want to do is to do a simple implement on the activity side, without creating an object instance of the service just to call a listener setter method. The way I want to do it is how Android does it with fragments<->activity. With fragments, the context is checked and then initialized with a context in the onAttach() callback.

I'm looking at the fragment example, where onAttach() callback has passed context and that context is casted to the interface class and set to the listener, how do I get the correct context, which is supposed to be an instance of the interface?

```
@Override 
public void onAttach(Context context) 
{ super.onAttach(context); 
if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) { mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context; 
}
```

Comment: are  you passing that activity to the class that does this  ***mListener.onSomethingHappened(AHHHappened);***...??

Comment: you don't set the `mListener` value anywhere: `mListener = ...`

Comment: Thx for the heads up. Looking through the fragment example, now I noticed in onAttach(Context context), the mListener are indeed assigned with the parameter context casted to the interface class. Now my question is, how do I pass the correct context from the activity to the service?

Comment: You should never pass a context from Activity to the service. Service has it's own context - it is a context itself. You can set a listener when you bind service to the activity

Comment: I'm looking at the fragment example, where onAttach() callback has passed context and that context is casted to the interface class and set to the listener, is that context the application's context or the service context? `@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

because you are not initializing the listener

Create a method for setting the listener in your `SomeService` class like this

```
public void setMylistener(OnSomethingHappenedListener onSomethingHappenedListener)
{
    mListener = onSomethingHappenedListener
}
```

and call this method before calling `SomeService` class

```
someService.setMylistener(onSomethingHappenedListener);
```

Thats It.

Comment: Is the method supposed to be a static setter method accessible from another activity? like the way you called it someService.setMylistener(..);

Comment: **No** static method doesn't work, you have to create object of that class.